# Bootstrap Validator still shows error message after setting value through jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator, jqbootstrapvalidation

I'm changing a value of a drop-down 01 based on another drop-down 02 via jquery `change()`. And i have implemented BootsrapValidation() to the form. My issue is if required field error message is displayed for the dropdown 01 and then i set dropdown 01 value from jquery. Yet the error message is still there.

I added `$('#form1').bootstrapValidator();` to the end of `change()` yet no luck. any ideas really appreciated.

Check the fiddle from here: https://jsfiddle.net/k2vtkka1/5/

here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('.subSort').change(function(){;
    var sub_code = $(this).val();
    var code_id = $(this).attr("id");

    var code_prefix = sub_code.substring(0, 4);
    var id_prefix = code_id.substring(4, 5);

    var new_sub_code = code_prefix+'102';
    var new_id_no = parseInt(id_prefix)+1;

    $('#sub_'+new_id_no).val(new_sub_code);
    $('#update_student_form').bootstrapValidator();
});


$('#update_student_form').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: { 
            sub_6: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select main sub 01 derived'
                }
               }
            }
        }
    })


    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
            $('#update_student_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();

        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(e.target);
        var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize()).done(function(data) {
            if (data.trim().length >0)
            {
                $('#error_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow");
            }
            else {
                $('#success_message').slideDown({ opacity: "show" }, "slow");
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: can you createa fiddle example of your problem? it will be easy to understand and rectify the problem

Comment: Hi, I created a fiddle. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/k2vtkka1/5/

Comment: check these steps; reload the page, click save. You can see the error message. now change Main Sub 01, Main Sub 01 Derived also get changed. but the error message is still there

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem:-

Actually the code:-

```
$('#sub_'+new_id_no).val(new_sub_code);
```

Is not changing the value in second select-box (although it's showing that value changed).That's why it's not proceeding further, after error came there.

You need to trigger `change()` there so that it actually change the value and then your validator get it.

So change the above line with this:-

```
$('#sub_'+new_id_no).val(new_sub_code).change();
```

Working example:-https://jsfiddle.net/fn0r4nvh/

Reference:- [change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Strange. I have never come up with this before. That means when using `$('#elementId').val('something')` doesn't trigger the event. And Bootstrap validator must be relying on the event trigger.

Comment: @guitarlass  actually it something like bootstap validator treated elements in different way and when you are doing some changes through external script code then it will not recognise those changes until we force it to recognise  via `change()`

Comment: Yes never had this with other validators. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Successfully tested `$('#elementId').trigger('change');` for this as well.

Comment: @guitarlass  great.glad to help you :):)